# Mapreduce job is not running

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

After installing and configuring my hadoop 2.7.1 in pseudo-distributed mode everything is running, as you can see in the

```
~$ jps
4825 Jps
4345 NameNode
4788 JobHistoryServer
4496 ResourceManager
```

Than i ran mapreduce example

```
  hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar pi 2 10
```

And the execution frezees (?)

```
  Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 10
15/07/14 08:40:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop          library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Starting Job
15/07/14 08:40:13 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at  master/10.0.0.4:8032
15/07/14 08:40:15 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process :  2
15/07/14 08:40:15 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
15/07/14 08:40:16 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job:  job_1436860512406_0002
15/07/14 08:40:17 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application   application_1436860512406_0002
15/07/14 08:40:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job:  http://master:8088/proxy/application_1436860512406_0002/
15/07/14 08:40:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1436860512406_0002
```

After 2 hours it shows same..

please give any idea..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here I can see when you execute  `jps` command

```
~$ jps
4825 Jps
4345 NameNode
4788 JobHistoryServer
4496 ResourceManager
```

it is not showing your `data-node`. Means your data node is down. You need to format it and start again.

I was having same issue on my server. The steps I have followed is:

1. `stop-all.sh`
2. `hadoop namenode -format`
3. `hadoop datanode -format`
4. Go to the actual directory where your hdfs namenode and datanode are located.
   Remove all the files using `sudo rm -rf *`
5. Remove files from tmp directory for e.g.  `app/hadoop/tmp/`
6. Start hadoop using `start-all.sh`
7. Check if everything is running or not using jps

Answer (score 0):

set  `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` and
`yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` in yarn configuration some higher
number and it should be resolved.

Read more from cloudera [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/apache-hadoop-yarn-avoiding-6-time-consuming-gotchas/)